# Why my state doesn't change sometimes. What is the reason?

Tags: reactjs

I have 6 buttons and when I click them the style is changing. However, it doesn't work regularly. I think it is due to my state controller but I couldn't solve the problem. I'm gonna describe it one by one now.

```js
class NavSec2 extends React.Component {
  state = {
    controller: "",
  };

  clickHandler(e) {
    this.props.actions.buttonActive();

    this.setState({ controller: e.target.className });
  }

  render() {
    const { isActive } = this.props.navState;
    const { controller } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="menu-buttons">
        <button
          onClick={(e) => this.clickHandler(e)}
          className={controller === "fas fa-home" && isActive ? "active" : ""}
        >
          <i className="fas fa-home"></i>
        </button>

        <button
          onClick={(e) => this.clickHandler(e)}
          className={
            controller === "far fa-play-circle" && isActive ? "active" : ""
          }
        >
          <i className="far fa-play-circle"></i>
        </button>

        <button
          onClick={(e) => this.clickHandler(e)}
          className={controller === "fas fa-store" && isActive ? "active" : ""}
        >
          <i className="fas fa-store"></i>
        </button>

        <button
          onClick={(e) => this.clickHandler(e)}
          className={controller === "fas fa-users" && isActive ? "active" : ""}
        >
          <i className="fas fa-users"></i>
        </button>

        <button
          onClick={(e) => this.clickHandler(e)}
          className={
            controller === "fas fa-gamepad" && isActive ? "active" : ""
          }
        >
          <i className="fas fa-gamepad"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NavSec2 navState={{}} actions={{ buttonActive: () => {}}} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

When I click a button, the controller state takes the value of icon's className (fa-home etc.). And I say to my button that if the controller state has your icon's className, and the isActive initial state (which I wrote in Redux and I don't have a problem with it) is true, you will add a class named 'active' to yourself.

They both happens. The controller state changes and the initial state turns true. When I click a button it changes color. However, I realize that sometimes my controller state doesn't change. I don't know why. What should I do ?

Comment: Your controller state didin't changes sometimes or not registed at all?

Comment: It doesn't change sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened because `<i></i>` not always targeted when clicking on `<button>`.

When accidentally clicked on `<button>` the `e.target.className` doesn't have value

You can manipulate it with `css` `<i>`covered up whole `<button>` area, it's prevent to misclicking

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood that the class name should be for buttons, not icons.